# Ajax array showing comma (,) in IE

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I do not understand as to why I have this issue arising. in Chrome and Firefox my ajax works well and there are so errors, however, when I run the Ajax request in IE the resulting output is the data but with a series of commas (,) at the top of my page.

example:

```
,
,
,
,
<tr> row1 </tr>
<tr> row2 </tr>
<tr> row3 </tr>
<tr> row4 </tr>
```

I want the output to be:

```
    <tr> row1 </tr>
    <tr> row2 </tr>
    <tr> row3 </tr>
    <tr> row4 </tr>
```

Code:
index.php

```
function indexMostRecent(linkcode) {
            var lines = '';
                $.ajax( {
                type: 'POST',
                url:'http://site.test.co.uk/shortlinks/nextLines.php', 
                data: { 'indexLeft': 1 },
                cache: false,
            }).done( function(jsondata) {

            lines = jsondata; 

            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( lines );

            $('#leftIndex').append( obj + '<tr id="less"><td> End </td></tr> ' );
            $('#indexLeft').remove();
        });
    };


    $('#indexLeft').click(indexMostRecent);
```

nextlines.php

```
<?php
include ('connection.php');
//these are the queries for the index page
    if(isSet($_POST['indexLeft'])){

            $mostRec = "SELECT * FROM shortlink_analytics ORDER BY hitTime DESC LIMIT 11, 999999";

            $array=array();

            $loadRec = mysql_query($mostRec);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($loadRec))
            {
                $array[] = '<tr><td class="overflow"><a href = "info.php?link='. $row['shortlink'] .'">hud.ac/' . $row['shortlink'] . '</a> - ' . $row['hitTime'] . '</td></tr>';
            } 

            echo json_encode($array);

        }

?>
```

what is causing this? 
How would I go about solving it?
Might it have something to do with the PHP that is getting called in during the AJAX request?

Comment: So, what's the code building this response? how are you logging the response?

Comment: no code, no context, nothing. we need to see some code here. Show us the relevant parts of the JS code.

Comment: Are you asking us to reproduce your issue (some kind of puzzle)? I do have some ideas.

Comment: Any chance your HTML looks similar to `<!-- [if ie] ,<br/>,<br/>,<br/>,<br/> [/if ie] -->`?

Comment: re the php code: please note that the `mysql_xx()` funcs are deprecated. recommend switching to `mysqli_xx()` or PDO if possible. (this is off-topic; not related to your issue, but important all the same)

Comment: @JanDvorak nope, there is nothing like that

Comment: Appending an array to an element ... doesn't quite work, as you see. Try appending one-by-one

Comment: @SDC I am aware of that and am currently in the process of transitioning from the PHP I know the the newer version as I have only touched on it a few times in the past I will stick with what works for the moment.

Comment: ... especially not when you concatenate the array with a string. I'm surprised that Chrome doesn't display the commas

Comment: try using `obj.join('')` rather than just `obj` in the `append()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( lines );
```

this will produce an array.

```
... .append( obj + '<tr ...
```

this will *convert the array to string* that looks very much like this: `'...</tr>,<tr ...'` before appending your new row.

If you want to concatenate the elements of the string client-side (why not do it server-side?), you can use the array method `join`:

```
... .append( obj.join('') + '<tr ...
```